Understanding the schwarz integrability condition for a linear system of pdes.
I have a system of (homogeneous, linear, second-order) equations that looks like:
\begin{align*}
u_{xx} &= A(x,y) u_x\\\\
u_{xy} &= B(x,y) u_x + C(x,y) u_y\\\\
u_{yy} &= D(x,y) u_y
\end{align*}
The book I'm reading (Doerfler et al., Calculating Curves) says that the "conditions for integrability of this system" are that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial_y} u_{xx} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} u_{xy}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial_y} u_{xy} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} u_{yy}$$
I know very little about systems of differential equations. I am guessing that "integrability" here means the existence of  a common solution to this system. I have managed to discover the term "Schwarz integrability conditions" and also attempted to read the wikipedia article on integrability conditions for differential systems, but it's written starting from a very high level.  So my question is:

Are these necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a solution to this system? How were these conditions derived?



A system of differential equations may give you more than one route to compute a mixed derivative. For example, if your system says that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = g(x,y)$, it follows that any solution to this differential equation will satisfy $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$ and also $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y \partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)$.

Because functions with continuous second derivatives have equal mixed partials— such as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$— these different formulas for computing the same mixed derivative must agree.

Therefore, you can derive formulas such as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ from the system of differential equations, which must hold for any solution to this system with continuous second derivatives.

In general, these are differential equations that are derived from the fact that the system provides more than one formula for computing some mixed derivative.  They are conditions that any solution to the system must satisfy, and so they are necessary conditions.



Yes, these are necessary conditions for integrability, i.e., existence of a solution. If $f \in C^3$, then applying Clairaut's Theorem to $f_x \in C_2$ gives that the second partial derivatives of $f_x$ commute:
$$\partial_y u_{xx} = u_{xxy} = u_{xyx} = \partial_x u_{xy}.$$ Substituting in this condition the p.d.e. equations yields additional equations that must be satisfied by $A, B, C, D$, their first derivatives, and the first derivatives of a solution $u$.
Here's a familiar example that illustrates the same point with just second derivatives: Consider the problem of finding a potential $f(x, y)$ for a vector field ${\bf F} = \langle P, Q \rangle$ on some open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, that is a function $f$ such that $\operatorname{grad} f = {\bf F}$. In components this condition is a p.d.e.:
\begin{align}
P &= f_x \\
Q &= f_y .
\end{align}
If we restrict our attention to $f \in C^2$, then Clairaut's Theorem gives that
$$P_y = f_{xy} = f_{yx} = Q_x .$$
Thus, a necessary solution for the existence of a solution to the p.d.e., i.e., a potential for $\bf F$, even locally, is that the components of $f$ satisfy the integrability condition
$$P_y = Q_x .$$
Indeed, sometimes we denote $\operatorname{curl} {\bf F} := Q_x - P_y$, so that the integrability condition is just $\operatorname{curl} {\bf F} = 0$. In this way, the curl operator measures quantitively the failure of $\bf F$ to have a potential.
In general such conditions do not guarantee global existence of solutions. For example, the vortex vector field, ${\bf V} := \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \langle -y, x\rangle$ satisfies the integrability condition, but a standard exercise in vector calculus shows that ${\bf V}$ has local potentials (i.e., the p.d.e. has a local solution) around any point in its domain but no (global) potential.
